# Secuencia especifica con Vectores para suma y multiplicación de cada posición

Tags: c++, algoritmos

Tengo problemas con un problema que me pide tener las siguientes operaciones con dos vectores diferentes de 10 espacios cada uno. Se me pide obtener la salida de la siguiente forma:

```
s[0] = v1[0] * v2[0]
s[1] = (v1[1] * v2[0]) + (v1[0] * v2[1])
s[2] = (v1[2] * v2[0]) + (v1[1] * v2[1]) + (v1[0] * v2[2])
s[3] = (v1[3] * v2[0]) + (v1[2] * v2[1]) + (v1[1] * v2[2]) + (v1[0] * v2[3])
```

Y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a las 10 (o 'n') posiciones.

Intente implementar con un for anidado de la siguiente forma:

```
int v1[10] = {1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1}, v2[10] = {1,2,3,1,4,0,0,0,0,0}, s[10];

for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    for(int j = i; j>= 0; j--){
        s[j] = (v1[i] * v2[j]) + s[j-1];
    }

    ( j == (i-1) ) ? cout << s[j] << " ";
}
```

Pero la salida que obtengo es:

> 0, 2, 5, 5, 9...

Y debería empezar por:

> 1, 2, 4, 4, 9, etc...

La secuencia que siguen las operaciones es la siguiente, tomando en cuenta los indices de cada array y multiplicándoselo por sí mismos dentro de cada corchete, para después sumar cada corchete, y almacenando cada operación del renglón de a continuación en un nuevo vector de salida:

```
                [0*0]
            [1*0] + [0*1]
        [2*0] + [1*1] + [0*2]
    [3*0] + [2*1] + [1*2] + [0*3]
  [4*0] + [3*1] + [2*2] + [1*3] +[0*4]
[5*0] + [4*1] + [3*2] + [2*3] +[1*4] + [0*5]
```

**En realidad solo me importan los primeros 5 dígitos de la operación o del bucle ya que a partir del 6 me basta con repetir el último por una condición en el problema...**

***Nota: El lenguaje es lo de menos ya que necesito implementarlo en 3 lenguajes diferentes, pudiendo ser C/C++, Python, Java, Javascript, etc, entonces con solo poder comprender la lógica del bucle es más que suficiente.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas, el valor de `s[i]` sigue el siguiente patrón.

`s[i] = v1[i] * v2[0] + v1[i-1] * v2[1] + ... + v1[0] * v2[i]`

En esencia solo necesitamos un ciclo para cada valor de `s`.

```
// Este ciclo es para calcular s[i]
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // Nos aseguramos que el valor inicial de s[i] sea cero
    s[i] = 0;
    
    // Calculamos s[i] según el valor de i siguiendo el patrón explicado previamente
    // Por ejemplo cuando i = 2
    // S[2] += S[2] * S[2 - 2], j = 2
    // S[2] += S[1] * S[2 - 1], j = 1
    // S[2] += S[0] * S[2 - 0], j = 0
    for (int j = i; j >= 0; --j) {
        s[i] += v1[j] * v2[i - j];
    }
}
```

Lo que está sucediendo es que por cada valor de `s[i]`, recorremos el rango `[0, i]`, para computar la sumatoria que planteas. Y utilizamos una especie de dos punteros para cada arreglo `v1` y `v2`, considerando que el índice para `v1` aumenta, y para `v2` disminuye, aunque realmente no importa, se podría manejar al revés, y es lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, es justamente la secuencia que necesitaba, aunque creo después del 5 bucle ya no cumple la condición es insignificante ahorita dada la condición de que debo tomar solo los primeros 5. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer la operación en tiempo de compilación si usas plantillas variádicas:

```
template <int size, int ... values>
void opera(const int (&v1)[size], const int (&v2)[size], int (&out)[size],
    const std::integer_sequence<int, values ...> &seq)
{
    ((out[values] = suma(v1, v2, std::make_integer_sequence<int, values + 1>{})), ...);
}
```

La plantilla anterior genera esta secuencia cuando se llama con `std::integer_sequence<int, 10>` como último parámetro:

```
out[0] = suma(v1, v2, out, std::make_integer_sequence<int, 1>,
…,
out[9] = suma(v1, v2, out, std::make_integer_sequence<int, 10>;
```

La función `suma`:

```
template <int size, int ... values>
int suma(const int (&v1)[size], const int (&v2)[size],
    const std::integer_sequence<int, values ...> &)
{
    constexpr auto count = sizeof...(values) - 1;

    if constexpr (count == 0)
        return v1[0] * v2[0];

    else
        return ((v1[count - values] * v2[values]) + ... + 0);
}
```

Genera las sumas en el formato que necesitas. Si añadimos una función auxiliar que nos deduzca los parámetros, el código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <int size, int ... values>
int suma(const int (&v1)[size], const int (&v2)[size], const std::integer_sequence<int, values ...> &)
{
    constexpr auto count = sizeof...(values) - 1;

    if constexpr (count == 0)
        return v1[0] * v2[0];

    else
        return ((v1[count - values] * v2[values]) + ... + 0);
}

template <int size, int ... values>
void opera(const int (&v1)[size], const int (&v2)[size], int (&out)[size], const std::integer_sequence<int, values ...> &seq)
{
    ((out[values] = suma(v1, v2, std::make_integer_sequence<int, values + 1>{})), ...);
}

template <int size>
void operar(const int (&v1)[size], const int (&v2)[size], int (&out)[size])
{
    opera(v1, v2, out, std::make_integer_sequence<int, size>{});
}

int main()
{
    int v1[10] = {1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1}, v2[10] = {1,2,3,1,4,0,0,0,0,0}, s[10]{};

    operar(v1, v2, s);

    for (const auto &v : s)
        std::cout << v << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLZboMwEHzGX7FSpcQUJwLapxz8SBRFFjERKlexjdpG@fXSXUOatlJvIXHszI5nh02bZpYWsjr0/VVepYXdK1jltTatkmXCLjVr8iI3jwljRpVNIQ3xKgM6f1IC6G0@n0MnC6t0whxiS8nTutLGwXzSRf6G6FsB78rxh7I2@8UCMXVQ7U6re6uqVNFhYtSnoxKY@OzIPNeiHpoWpDU1KlgUXTtbdYY8PrT4MINoyZiXZ3Bp4SN9DaHPPK9VxrYVdNEm3MI1dDE@qUcVWl1gzpEwNM5GQyN7/PAhcGEEqLpkp58l1tX5HupGtb/NbCjU1vwxRYRckJyjxnkESpB@XxchOxaDWCnv1O5LxQCi5HjyfUHan83@dtb2n8M650NqZ6sIfu/X@UCnziKJljKvuFOjL/zBUUghHCMRikic7@460TkXPBY3WL1Fxnghrgk@nmh3xjFfg/SpmNVu92hEt7WTDhYI4Y4547hcBlYr6Og2hSm1jMsXouO@f06zQh50P0P6Og2CWL4A)</kbd>.